# Getting error when trying to define VPC access for google cloud run

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-vpc

Trying to deploy a google cloud run with a private VPC connector instance using a node.js script. Keep getting this error when I try to run it:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Violation in CreateServiceRequest.service.template.vpc_access.connector: one and only one of connector and network_interfaces must be set.
```

I've spent time looking at google's documentation and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Script deploys the image fine when I remove the vpcAccess bit. Judging from the error, I must be defining 'connector' incorrectly. What am I missing here?

```
  const parent = 'projects/***/locations/us-central1';

  const service = {
        template: {
            vpcAccess: [
                {
                    connector: 'projects/***/locations/us-central1/connectors/socket-connector-name',
                    egress: 'private-ranges-only'
                }
            ],
            containers: [
                {
                    image: '***',
                },
            ]
        },
    };
  
  const serviceId = 'abc123';
  
  const { ServicesClient } = require('@google-cloud/run').v2;
  const runClient = new ServicesClient();
  
  async function callCreateService() {
    const request = {
      parent,
      service,
      serviceId,
    };
  
    const [operation] = await runClient.createService(request);
    const [response] = await operation.promise();
    console.log(response);
  }
  
  callCreateService();
```

Comment: Hmm, strange... Maybe an issue in the library. Recently the Direct VPC egress has been released and it could be a side effect.

Comment: Yikes @guillaumeblaquiere do you know where I can find info on this update? I'm not sure how to work this problem without any sort of documentation.

Comment: The recently released Direct VPC egress mentioned by @guillaumeblaquiere can be found in Google Cloud's [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/announcing-direct-vpc-egress-for-cloud-run) and the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/vpc-direct-vpc).